# JDBCTemplate to delete the records based on time, never completes

Tags: spring, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

The following statement in my code never completes the execution. I am not sure, if some thing wrong with the below query.

```
     public void delete(String username) {
        LocalDateTime sixMonthsOld = LocalDateTime.now().minusMonths(6);
        this.jdbcTemplate.update("delete from log_access where accesstime <= ?", Timestamp.valueOf(sixMonthsOld));
      }
```

But when I try the other query, it works fine

```
  public void delete() {
    this.jdbcTemplate.update("delete from log_access where username <= ?", "aaa");    

  }
```

There are hardly 50 to 100 records in DB. Not sure why the delete query with time takes long time.

Comment: Take a thread dump and see why it hangs. Probably there is no free connection or there is just a lot of data to remove.

Comment: @M.Deinum. Its is very very small data and there are lot of free threads

Comment: Or the delete statement conflicts with a different transaction and is waiting for a lock

Comment: I was not talking about threads but about connections. If you take a thread dump you can see why a thread is hung (is it on getting a connection, executing the statement etc.).

Comment: Try to find out what is going on in DB server. DB server log may help you to find the problem

Comment: @M.Deinum I tried with other query and it works fine. Not sure why the just query with date hangs

Answer (score 0):

I guess it happens because of huge amount of data to be deleted so you got timeout or rollback segment is too small to keep so many records.
Split the delete into set of smaller ones.

```
 public void delete(String username) {
    LocalDateTime sixMonthsOld = LocalDateTime.now().minusMonths(6);
    for (int i=0; i<maxIdInTheLogAccesstable; i+=1000) {
        this.jdbcTemplate.update("delete from log_access where accesstime <= ? and id<?", Timestamp.valueOf(sixMonthsOld), i);
    }
  }
```

Thus you will delete step by step. Id range 1000 could be modified to be 10k or more depending on real max id and amount of data you have and server.